# Unexpected Crash Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios7, xcode6.3.1

I could not detect what is causing this crash only in iOS 7. All exception is also given but not working. In iOS 8 all working fine. Here is my crash log.

2015-05-07 19:53:38.731 gonogo[5717:607] Objective: {objective 0x799dda90: <750:28455, 251:948, 250:562> + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796a24b0.posErrorMarker{id: 2377} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796a6730.posErrorMarker{id: 2379} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x796ab800.negError{id: 2370} + <750:-4, 251:-4>*0x796b4ee0.marker{id: 2304} + <251:-1>*0x796b6440.marker{id: 2344} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x796b6470.marker{id: 2347} + <750:1>*0x796b64a0.marker{id: 2350} + <251:-1>*0x796b6870.marker{id: 2353} + <750:3.44828, 251:0.758621>*0x796b68a0.marker{id: 2356} + <251:-1>*0x796b68d0.marker{id: 2359} + <750:3.44828, 251:0.758621>*0x796b6900.marker{id: 2362} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796b81f0.posErrorMarker{id: 2375} + <251:-1>*0x796b9b00.marker{id: 2322} + <251:-1>*0x796b9b30.marker{id: 2324} + <251:-1>*0x796b9b90.marker{id: 2331} + <750:2.2069, 251:1.17241>*0x796b9bc0.marker{id: 2332} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796ba400.posErrorMarker{id: 2373} + <750:-2, 251:-2>*0x796bb360.marker{id: 2301} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x796bc000.negError{id: 2372} + <251:-1>*0x796bf9e0.marker{id: 2335} + <251:-1>*0x796bfa10.marker{id: 2336} + <251:1>*0x796bfa40.marker{id: 2337} + <750:4.68966, 251:2.34483>*0x796bfa70.marker{id: 2339} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x796c76e0.negError{id: 2531} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x796c7720.negError{id: 2533} + <251:-1>*0x796cc7d0.marker{id: 2307} + <251:-1>*0x796cc830.marker{id: 2317} + <251:1>*0x796cc860.marker{id: 2318} + <251:1>*0x796cde00.marker{id: 2384} + <750:-3.44828, 251:-0.758621>*0x796dbb10.marker{id: 2388} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796de7c0.posErrorMarker{id: 2418} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796de820.posErrorMarker{id: 2420} + <251:1>*0x796dedb0.marker{id: 2425} + <750:-3.44828, 251:-0.758621>*0x796dee10.marker{id: 2429} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x796df380.negError{id: 2411} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x796df3c0.negError{id: 2413} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796e0360.posErrorMarker{id: 2414} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796e03b0.posErrorMarker{id: 2416} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796e2d00.posErrorMarker{id: 2458} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796e2d60.posErrorMarker{id: 2460} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796e3470.posErrorMarker{id: 2454} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796e34c0.posErrorMarker{id: 2456} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x796e3e10.negError{id: 2451} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x796e3ec0.negError{id: 2453} + <251:1>*0x796e4520.marker{id: 2465} + <750:-3.44828, 251:-0.758621>*0x796e4580.marker{id: 2469} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796e6280.posErrorMarker{id: 2498} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796e62e0.posErrorMarker{id: 2500} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796e68b0.posErrorMarker{id: 2496} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796e7430.posErrorMarker{id: 2494} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x796e8280.negError{id: 2491} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x796e82c0.negError{id: 2493} + <251:1>*0x796e8d60.marker{id: 2505} + <750:-3.44828, 251:-0.758621>*0x796e8dc0.marker{id: 2509} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796eab70.posErrorMarker{id: 2534} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796eabb0.posErrorMarker{id: 2536} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796eb330.posErrorMarker{id: 2538} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x796eccd0.posErrorMarker{id: 2540} + <251:1>*0x796ed2f0.marker{id: 2545} + <750:-3.44828, 251:-0.758621>*0x796ed350.marker{id: 2549} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x7976f380.negError{id: 1990} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x7976f3d0.negError{id: 1988} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x7976f6f0.negError{id: 1986} + <750:1, 250:-3>*0x7976f740.negError{id: 1984} + <250:4>*0x7976f740.posErrorMarker{id: 1983} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x7976faa0.negError{id: 1980} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x7976fae0.negError{id: 1982} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x79788dd0.posErrorMarker{id: 2645} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x7978f1a0.posErrorMarker{id: 2649} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x797c97e0.posErrorMarker{id: 2653} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x797dedd0.posErrorMarker{id: 2647} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x797e2c90.posErrorMarker{id: 2655} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x797e4800.posErrorMarker{id: 2651} + <750:3.44828, 251:0.758621>*0x79870e90.marker{id: 2294} + <251:-1>*0x79870ec0.marker{id: 2291} + <750:3.44828, 251:0.758621>*0x79870ef0.marker{id: 2288} + <251:-1>*0x79870f20.marker{id: 2285} + <750:1>*0x79871100.marker{id: 2282} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x79871130.marker{id: 2279} + <251:-1>*0x79871160.marker{id: 2276} + <750:4.68966, 251:2.34483>*0x798711c0.marker{id: 2271} + <251:1>*0x798711f0.marker{id: 2269} + <251:-1>*0x79871220.marker{id: 2268} + <251:-1>*0x79871250.marker{id: 2267} + <750:2.2069, 251:1.17241>*0x79871280.marker{id: 2264} + <251:-1>*0x798712b0.marker{id: 2263} + <251:-1>*0x79871310.marker{id: 2256} + <251:-1>*0x79871340.marker{id: 2254} + <251:1>*0x798713a0.marker{id: 2250} + <251:-1>*0x798713d0.marker{id: 2249} + <251:-1>*0x79871430.marker{id: 2239} + <750:-4, 251:-4>*0x79871830.marker{id: 2236} + <750:-2, 251:-2>*0x79872310.marker{id: 2233} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x798e19c0.posErrorMarker{id: 2641} + <750:-2, 251:-2>*0x798e7fb0.marker{id: 2029} + <750:-4, 251:-4>*0x798edfd0.marker{id: 2032} + <750:-2, 251:-2>*0x798ef100.marker{id: 2097} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x798f00b0.posErrorMarker{id: 2643} + <251:-1>*0x798f0890.marker{id: 2035} + <251:-1>*0x798f08f0.marker{id: 2045} + <251:1>*0x798f0920.marker{id: 2046} + <251:-1>*0x798f13e0.marker{id: 2050} + <251:-1>*0x798f1410.marker{id: 2052} + <251:-1>*0x798f1470.marker{id: 2059} + <750:2.2069, 251:1.17241>*0x798f14a0.marker{id: 2060} + <251:-1>*0x798f14d0.marker{id: 2063} + <251:-1>*0x798f1500.marker{id: 2064} + <251:1>*0x798f1530.marker{id: 2065} + <750:4.68966, 251:2.34483>*0x798f1560.marker{id: 2067} + <251:-1>*0x798f15c0.marker{id: 2072} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x798f15f0.marker{id: 2075} + <750:1>*0x798f1620.marker{id: 2078} + <251:-1>*0x798f17d0.marker{id: 2081} + <750:3.44828, 251:0.758621>*0x798f1800.marker{id: 2084} + <251:-1>*0x798f1830.marker{id: 2087} + <750:3.44828, 251:0.758621>*0x798f1860.marker{id: 2090} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x798f27f0.posErrorMarker{id: 2659} + <750:-4, 251:-4>*0x798f2b50.marker{id: 2100} + <251:-1>*0x798f2f50.marker{id: 2103} + <251:-1>*0x798f2fb0.marker{id: 2113} + <251:1>*0x798f2fe0.marker{id: 2114} + <251:-1>*0x798f3040.marker{id: 2118} + <251:-1>*0x798f3070.marker{id: 2120} + <251:-1>*0x798f30d0.marker{id: 2127} + <750:2.2069, 251:1.17241>*0x798f3100.marker{id: 2128} + <251:-1>*0x798f3130.marker{id: 2131} + <251:-1>*0x798f3160.marker{id: 2132} + <251:1>*0x798f3190.marker{id: 2133} + <750:4.68966, 251:2.34483>*0x798f31c0.marker{id: 2135} + <251:-1>*0x798f3220.marker{id: 2140} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x798f3250.marker{id: 2143} + <750:1>*0x798f3280.marker{id: 2146} + <251:-1>*0x798f3460.marker{id: 2149} + <750:3.44828, 251:0.758621>*0x798f3490.marker{id: 2152} + <251:-1>*0x798f34c0.marker{id: 2155} + <750:3.44828, 251:0.758621>*0x798f34f0.marker{id: 2158} + <750:-2, 251:-2>*0x798f7670.marker{id: 2165} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x798f79d0.posErrorMarker{id: 2657} + <750:-4, 251:-4>*0x798f8130.marker{id: 2168} + <251:-1>*0x798f8530.marker{id: 2171} + <251:-1>*0x798f8590.marker{id: 2181} + <251:1>*0x798f85c0.marker{id: 2182} + <251:-1>*0x798f8620.marker{id: 2186} + <251:-1>*0x798f8650.marker{id: 2188} + <251:-1>*0x798f86b0.marker{id: 2195} + <750:2.2069, 251:1.17241>*0x798f86e0.marker{id: 2196} + <251:-1>*0x798f8710.marker{id: 2199} + <251:-1>*0x798f8740.marker{id: 2200} + <251:1>*0x798f8770.marker{id: 2201} + <750:4.68966, 251:2.34483>*0x798f87a0.marker{id: 2203} + <251:-1>*0x798f8800.marker{id: 2208} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x798f8830.marker{id: 2211} + <750:1>*0x798f8860.marker{id: 2214} + <251:-1>*0x798f8a40.marker{id: 2217} + <750:3.44828, 251:0.758621>*0x798f8a70.marker{id: 2220} + <251:-1>*0x798f8aa0.marker{id: 2223} + <750:3.44828, 251:0.758621>*0x798f8ad0.marker{id: 2226} + <250:1>*0x79979810.marker{id: 1911} + <250:-1>*0x79997d80.marker{id: 1942} + <250:1>*0x799c8500.marker{id: 1909} + <250:1>*0x799d4560.marker{id: 1907} + <250:1>*0x799e2e40.marker{id: 1928} + <250:1>*0x799e3120.marker{id: 1945} + <250:-2>*0x799e3150.marker{id: 1946} + <250:1>*0x799e34c0.marker{id: 1947} + <999:2>*0x799e3720.negError{id: 1914} + <999:2>*0x799e4530.negError{id: 1917} + <250:-1>*0x799e4d00.marker{id: 1936} + <750:-7.07537e-08>*UIImageView:0x796b59e0.Height{id: 1690} + <750:7.07537e-08>*UIImageView:0x796b59e0.Width{id: 1689} + <999:1>*_UILayoutGuide:0x799d7040.Width{id: 1918} + <999:1>*_UILayoutGuide:0x799dade0.Width{id: 1915}}

Comment: I cannot detect it either; all I can see is garbage.

Comment: This doesn't look like a crash log. What are you doing in the app? Can you show some code?

Comment: i did hit and trial and removed all proportional height constraint from image used in tableview cell and its solved. thanks to all.